# remove slash \ from converted json string

Tags: ios, swift4

> [{\"destination\":\"Bhainsa\",\"travelMode\":\"Flight\",\"company\":\"Yes\",\"origin\":\"Adilabad\"}]

// This is MY Code

```
let data1 = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrat2, options: [])

let jsonString = String(data: data1, encoding: .utf8)!
```

Comment: Are you sure there are backslashes?. Usually they are virtually added to escape double quotes in a literal string.

Comment: ▿ 0 : 4 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : destination
      - value : Anantapur
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : travelMode
      - value : Flight
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : company
      - value : Yes
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - key : origin
      - value : Adilabad   this is my Array and i converted this in String Formate . and i got this result . "[{\"destination\":\"Anantapur\",\"travelMode\":\"Flight\",\"company\":\"Yes\",\"origin\":\"Adilabad\"}]" but i don't want this Single slash . you know how to remove this Single slash \

Comment: Once again the backslashes are added when you `print` the string. There are no backslashes unless one of the dictionary values is a JSON string. Try it in Playground. The backslashes should **not** appear in the result sidebar.

Comment: What about testing what @vadian said? Just create a `UILabel` somewhere and set its `text` property to `jsonString`. Check if you see again the backslash.

Answer (score 1):

You may need

```
let str = """
[{\"destination\":\"Bhainsa\",\"travelMode\":\"Flight\",\"company\":\"Yes\",\"origin\":\"Adilabad\"}]
"""  
let res = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: str.data(using:.utf8)!, options: []) as! [[String:Any]] 
let resStr = "\(res)"
print(resStr) // [["origin": Adilabad, "travelMode": Flight, "company": Yes, "destination": Bhainsa]]
```

---

```
let ggg = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
print(ggg) // [{"destination":"Bhainsa","travelMode":"Flight","company":"Yes","origin":"Adilabad"}]
```

Comment: it's came jsonobject formate but i want return in String formate

Comment: and i can't make my string like this  //   """
[{\"destination\":\"Bhainsa\",\"travelMode\":\"Flight\",\"company\":\"Yes\",\"origin\":\"Adilabad\"}] """  because i made one array then converted in string formate but here is single slash come but i want to remove single slash and return in only string formate  . i want return this Formate //  "[{"destination":"Port Blair","travelMode":"Flight","company":"No","origin":"Adilabad"}]"

Comment: let ggg = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "") . i already try this code but it's not workin. i got same result when i use this code . this is same  result  "[{\"destination\":\"Adilabad\",\"travelMode\":\"Flight\",\"company\":\"Yes\",\"origin\":\"Port Blair\"}]"

Comment: i converted my Array in String and i got this string  "[{\"destination\":\"Bhainsa\",\"travelMode\":\"Flight\",\"company\":\"Yes\",\"origin\":\"Adilabad\"}]" but i want to remove this Single slash also . and after remove i want in string formate not in jsonobject